# Euler's characteristic and planar graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Prove the following statement or find a counter-example. For all $n$, $m$, $f$ with $n - m + f = 2$ and for which there exists a simple graph with $\alpha_0 = n$, $\alpha_1 = m$ there exists also a simple planar graph with $\alpha_0 = n$, $\alpha_1 = m$, and $\alpha_2 = f$.

I know that a simple graph is the one that doesn't have loops, but I'm having difficulty finding a counter-example here or proving the statement above. I thought of trees, while they always satisfy $n - m + f = 2$, but then again they are planar graphs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $K_5$ is a simple non-planar graph with $n = 5$ and $m = 10$. What are the possible graphs with $n = 5$ and $m = 10$?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking this also, so $f$ must be equal to 7, in order for the about equality to hold. Can we think of some isomorphism of $K_5$? I'm having hard time coming up with a similar graph.

Comment: If a simple graph has $5$ vertices and $10$ edges then it is $K_5$...

Comment: Well, I didn't know that the answer to this problem would be so easy, just to find a graph that is not planar.

Comment: It isn't just a non-planar graph - it is a non-planar graph where every simple graph with the same number of vertices and edges is also non-planar.

Comment: Is there anywhere a proof that all graphs with $5$ vertices and $10$ edges are non-planar?

Comment: By Euler's formula, for any planar graph $m \leq 3n - 6$, but in this case $10 > 3\cdot 5 - 6$.